Why is Leetcode compiler different
public class Solution {
    public int AddDigits(int num) {
        string strNum = num.ToString();

        while (strNum.Length > 1)
        {
                int num1 = int.Parse(strNum[0].ToString());
                int num2 = int.Parse(strNum[1].ToString());
                num1 += num2;
                strNum = num1.ToString();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(strNum);
        Console.ReadLine();
        return int.Parse(strNum);
    }
}

The following code works with any number other than zero on leetcode website compiler. When I call the function passing the value 0 into num it fails to return anything at all into the output field (basically just crashed). If I take away Console.Readline(); it works fine with 0 does anyone know why this is? it seems to be only on leetcodes compiler.

no repro. also the problem can be solved without string conversion, via integer division
